# jQuery animate to change background color (not working in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a simple horizontal menu. All I want is for the background of the li a I am hovering over to animate from white to gray. All is working well in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome. What could the reason be?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav ul li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5' }, 500);
    },function(){
          $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#FFF' }, 500);
     })
})
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estimator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products & Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--end of nav div-->
```

I know this is REALLY simple stuff, I've done it many times before. But like I said, it doesn't work in Chrome.

FIXED:

I just changed plugins. As I said, it's been a while since I've done anything with jQuery. Completely forgot about jQuery UI. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI (or other plugin)? You need to if you want to animate the background color. Works fine if you do: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/899Wn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried it ( [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/H66uh/) ) and it doesn't work for me in any browser.

Which is the expected outcome since jQuery doesn't support color animations out of the box. You have to use the jQuery UI ( which is huge ) or a plugin like [**this**](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

As an alternative you can do this with CSS3 transitions - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H66uh/1/)

```css
a {
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
       -moz-transition: background-color .5s;
        -ms-transition: background-color .5s;
         -o-transition: background-color .5s;
            transition: background-color .5s;
}  

a:hover {
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
}
​
```

Comment: Oh crap, I meant to mention that I had a color plugin as well... Which is why it works in the other two browsers (I figure).

Comment: CSS3 transitions won't work properly on IE, I wonder if anyone is actually using them for animations?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Too bad for IE users :) However it's 2012 and people finally have realized that the websites not necessarily look the same in ALL browsers. And they've finally accepted the idea of progressive enhancement and/or graceful degradation. Twitter, for example, uses a LOT of CSS3 stuff and no IE9 users complained so far :)

Comment: Hmm... The site's I've made are looking the same in every browser, except css3 parts (border-radius,rgba). So you're saying me that websites can look different on other browsers?